# how to calculate a running total in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains precipitation data that looks like this

```
Date Time, Raw Measurement, Site ID, Previous Raw Measurement, Raw - Previous
2020-05-06 14:15:00,12.56,8085,12.56,0.0
2020-05-06 14:30:00,12.56,8085,12.56,0.0
2020-05-06 14:45:00,12.56,8085,12.56,0.0
2020-05-06 15:00:00,2.48,8085,12.56,-10.08
2020-05-06 15:30:00,2.48,8085,2.47,0.01
2020-05-06 15:45:00,2.48,8085,2.48,0.0
2020-05-06 16:00:00,2.50,8085,2.48,0.02
2020-05-06 16:15:00,2.50,8085,2.50,0.0
2020-05-06 16:30:00,2.50,8085,2.50,0.0
2020-05-06 16:45:00,2.51,8085,2.50,0.01
2020-05-06 17:00:00,2.51,8085,2.51,0.0
```

I would like to use the last column 'Raw - Previous', which is simply the difference between the most recent observation and the previous observation, to create a running total of the positive changes to make an accumulation column. From time to time I have to empty out the rain gauge so the 'Raw - Previous' will be negative when that occurs and I would like to filter this out of my df while keeping a tally of the total accumulation of the gauge. I've come across solutions that use
`df.sum()`
but from what I can gather, they only provide the total sum of the entire column and not the running total after each row.

In all my goal is to have something like this

```
Date Time, Raw Measurement, Site ID, Previous Raw Measurement, Raw - Previous, Total Accumulation
2020-05-06 14:15:00,12.56,8085,12.56,0.0,12.56
2020-05-06 14:30:00,12.56,8085,12.56,0.0,12.56
2020-05-06 14:45:00,12.56,8085,12.56,0.0,12.56
2020-05-06 15:00:00,2.48,8085,12.56,-10.08,12.56
2020-05-06 15:15:00,2.47,8085,2.48,-0.01,12.56
2020-05-06 15:30:00,2.48,8085,2.47,0.01,12.57
2020-05-06 15:45:00,2.48,8085,2.48,0.0,12.57
2020-05-06 16:00:00,2.50,8085,2.48,0.02,12.59
2020-05-06 16:15:00,2.50,8085,2.50,0.0,12.59
2020-05-06 16:30:00,2.50,8085,2.50,0.0,12.59
2020-05-06 16:45:00,2.51,8085,2.50,0.01,12.60
2020-05-06 17:00:00,2.51,8085,2.51,0.0,12.60
```

EDIT: Changed title to better reflect what the question became

Comment: Your sample data and your expected data are not consistent., The two columns `Previous Raw Measurement` and ``Raw - Previous` are very different between the two dataframes.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks for pointing this out. I changed some by hand to better highlight what I want to do. I will fix it!

Comment: Also, the output is incorrect for the last two rows, which I picked up from the output in my answer.

Comment: @DavidErickson I forgot the tenths 0! but thank you for pointing out.. it's been one of those mornings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `clip()` to clip out negative values followed by `cumsum` for accumulative sum of the differences:

```
df['Total'] = df['Raw - Previous'].clip(lower=0).cumsum() + df['Raw Measurement'].iloc[0]
```

Output:

```
0     12.56
1     12.56
2     12.56
3     12.56
4     12.56
5     12.57
6     12.57
7     12.59
8     12.59
9     12.59
10    12.60
11    12.60
Name: Raw - Previous, dtype: float64
```

Comment: That looks too small and could be floating point error. Anyhow, you can adjust the `lower` in `clip` function.

Answer (score 1):

`np.where` will also do the job.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df['Total Accumulation'] = np.where((df['Raw - Previous'] > 0), df['Raw - Previous'], 0).cumsum() + df.iloc[0,3]
df
```

Output:

```
    Date Time   Raw Measurement Site ID Previous Raw Measurement    Raw - Previous  Total Accumulation
0   2020-05-06 14:15:00 12.56   8085    12.56   0.00    12.56
1   2020-05-06 14:30:00 12.56   8085    12.56   0.00    12.56
2   2020-05-06 14:45:00 12.56   8085    12.56   0.00    12.56
3   2020-05-06 15:00:00 2.48    8085    12.56   -10.08  12.56
4   2020-05-06 15:30:00 2.48    8085    2.47    0.01    12.57
5   2020-05-06 15:45:00 2.48    8085    2.48    0.00    12.57
6   2020-05-06 16:00:00 2.50    8085    2.48    0.02    12.59
7   2020-05-06 16:15:00 2.50    8085    2.50    0.00    12.59
8   2020-05-06 16:30:00 2.50    8085    2.50    0.00    12.59
9   2020-05-06 16:45:00 2.51    8085    2.50    0.10    12.69
10  2020-05-06 17:00:00 2.51    8085    2.51    0.00    12.69
```